# Scala map value extends interface

Tags: java, scala

This method is in a Java library we are calling

```
   public void setNumbers(Map<Integer, ? extends COSObjectable> numbers) {
...
    }
```

I have a mixed Java/Scala project, I moved working code from a Java class into a Scala class and now I can't get this call to work from Scala. The best I've been able to get is

```
  val numbers = new util.HashMap[Integer, _ <: COSObjectable ]
  node.setNumbers(numbers)
```

which is failing to compile with

class type required but java.util.HashMap[Integer, _ <: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.COSObjectable] found

The COSObjectable parameter of the map is a java interface

```
public interface COSObjectable {
    COSBase getCOSObject();
}
```

I'm not sure Scala likes this syntax when used with an interface. It seems to be saying I can only do this with a class.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe I was just trying too hard, taking off the _ <: seems to work

```
val numbers = new util.HashMap[Integer, COSObjectable ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work with:

```
object Tes {
  case class RandomStuff()
  val numbers = new java.util.HashMap[Integer, _ <: RandomStuff ]
}
```

or

```
  trait COSObjectable {
    def getCOSObject: Nothing
  }

  val numbers: Map[Integer, _ <: COSObjectable ] = Map.empty
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a class you need to use a specific type, not a wildcard.  Just like in Java you cannot do `new util.HashMap<Integer, ? extends COSObjectable>` you can do the equivalent `new util.HashMap[Integer, _ <: COSObjectable]`.

You need to specify the acutal type like `new util.HashMap[Integer, COSObjectable]` (or whatever subtype of `COSObjectable` you require).